# Using Count with Count Distinct and Group By

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have two tables, one for `employees` which has `id`, `name` and `company` columns and another table for survey `results` which has `employee_id`, `questions_id`, `answer` as one employee to many results.

```
|---------------------|
| id | name | company |
|---------------------|

|-----------------------------------------|
| id | employee_id | question_id | answer |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

I want to `Select` total number of employees for each company, and total participants from each company in the survey.

I tried the following query, but it's taking too much time to execute:

```
SELECT employees.company as x, COUNT(DISTINCT (results.employee_id)) "Total Surveys", (SELECT COUNT(employees.id) FROM employees WHERE company = x) "Headcount"
FROM results
JOIN employees ON results.employee_id = employees.id
GROUP BY employees.company
```

Result

```
|--------------------------------|
|  x | Total Surveys | Headcount |
|--------------------------------|
| C1 |       15      |    3      |
| C2 |       10      |    5      |
|--------------------------------|
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cafc15/2)

Any recommendations?

Comment: "taking too much time to execute", how much time is "too much"? Also, could you tell us which indices you have put on the tables, the amount of data you have in each table, and the query execution plan? 
An SQLFiddle with some dummy data would be very handy too!

Comment: As @FMashiro says, an SQLFiddle will greatly help. I also think that the query you wrote is wrong, because you count the number of employee for each company before joining them with the results, so you 'll always have the total number of employee, with no linking to the actual results.

Comment: @FMashiro just updated the question with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results you want by a `LEFT JOIN` from `employees` to `results`; then you can count both values without a subquery:

```
SELECT e.company, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT r.employee_id) AS `Total Surveys`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS `HeadCount`
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN results r ON r.employee_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.company
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cafc15/3)

Comment: @CairoCoder this query does return the correct results for your sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cafc15/3. There isn't enough data in the question to determine whether it is significantly faster although I would expect it to be given that it is saving a lot of queries.